# Sql im stuck on left join and sum

Tags: php, sql, sum, left-join, phalcon

I have got two tables, in the first one is Genkeys there are: keys id of team id of task and boolean if was key used.

The second one is Tasks there are only: id of task and number of points for completing the task and I need to sum how much users have total points at the time.

I was trying this request:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Tasks
LEFT JOIN
  used
WHERE 
  team = $id
FROM Genkeys 
SELECT 
  SUM points
WHERE  
  used = 0
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Is *that* your actual query? That is not a valid SQL instruction! Please edit your question and tell us *exaclty* what you want to do

Comment: add structure or data from tables

Comment: Sorry guys I am newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have tables Genkeys(team, task) and Tasks(task, points)...

```
select team,
sum(points) totalpoints
from Genkeys
join Tasks
on Genkeys.task=Tasks.task
group by team
```

The exact SQL verbage will change depending on the database engine you are using.